# Bond yield with known DV01

Tags: fixed-income, duration, sensitivities

Is there a way to calculate the yield of a bond knowing the DV01 and duration (numerical values) and knowing all other parameters of $V$ (maturity, coupon, etc.)?
$$DV01=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}$$

Comment: It's not completely clear that "all other parameters" are here but bonds with the same duration and very different yields are quite common. After all, the duration just measures one aspect of the risk exposure of a bond whereas the yield captures information about the entire package of risk exposures.

Comment: One can ESTIMATE it. The problem is that the coupon willl change the duration and Dv01, for any bond of known tenor. So it can't be basis-point-perfect.... but if you assume that the coupon is equal to yield, you will never have a bad guess.

Comment: Once you know the parameters (i.e. the precise description of the cash flows) what you need to find yield is the price. The ModDuration (or Dv01) is a also a function of price. So by trying various prices until you match the ModDuration you could roughly estimate the price and then plug it into the equation to get yield. But it seems like a sloppy and inaccurate procedure.